# call a function using data attribute

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='cmenu esc' id='cma'>
<div class='cmitem' data-fn='itemcut'>CUT</div>
<div class='cmitem' data-fn='itempaste'>PASTE</div>
<div class='cmitem' data-fn='itemdel'>DELETE</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.cmitem').click(function(){
    var fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    $(window)[fn]();
});

function itemcut(){
    console.log('test');
}
```

Error:
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fn is not a function`

So how to call a function this way ?

Comment: `window[fn]()`.  Remove the jQuery stuff from your call.

Comment: @Taplar, it works, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery does not directly expose Element properites.  You have to use the `attr()` or `prop()` or `data()` methods.  However, there is no point in using jQuery on the window in this case.  Just reference it directly.

```js
$('.cmitem').click(function() {
  //changed to use data() rather than attr()
  var fn = $(this).data('fn');
  var targetFunction = window[fn];
  
  //added some safety checking
  if (typeof targetFunction === 'function') {
    targetFunction();
  }
});

function itemcut() {
  console.log('test');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cmenu esc' id='cma'>
  <div class='cmitem' data-fn='itemcut'>CUT</div>
  <div class='cmitem' data-fn='itempaste'>PASTE</div>
  <div class='cmitem' data-fn='itemdel'>DELETE</div>
</div>
```